# JENA SPARQL RESULTSET throws an error

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I am running a quite simple sparql query through JENA. But I get an error as stated below:

My query works in dbpedia.org. In addition I put all the JAR files needed.

When I debug the code, I saw that the error comes from RESULTSET line.

Is there any suggestion?

Thanks in advance....

My code:

```
package connectingurl;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.*;



public class DBpediaQuery {

public static void main( String[] args ) {



   String s2 = "PREFIX yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>\n" +
               "PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>\n" +
               "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n" +
               "PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>\n" +
               "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\n" +
               "PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>\n" +
               "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
               "PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>\n" +
               "PREFIX foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>\n" +

       "SELECT DISTINCT *\n" +
                "WHERE {\n" +
                   "?city      rdf:type dbpedia-owl:PopulatedPlace .\n" +
                   "?city      rdfs:label ?label.\n" +
                   "?city      dbpedia-owl:country ?country .\n" +
                   "?country   dbpprop:commonName  ?country_name.\n" +

                   "OPTIONAL  { ?city   foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf   ?web }.\n" +

                   "FILTER (  lang(?label) = 'en' && regex(?country, 'Germany') && regex(?label, 'Homburg')) \n" +
                "} \n" +
                ""; 

            Query query = QueryFactory.create(s2); //s2 = the query above
            QueryExecution qExe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService( "http://dbpedia.org/snorql", query );
            ResultSet results = qExe.execSelect(); 
            ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ; 


}
```

}

Error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
(org.apache.jena.riot.stream.JenaIOEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Failure 
initializing default system SSL context
...

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
...


Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
...
```

Comment: Can you try http://dbpedia.org/sparql as your service instead of http://dbpedia.org/snorql

Comment: Thanks your response @Ravi Kumar. I have tried but the result is the same.

Comment: I think you'll need to show the whole stacktrace.  There's nothing obviously doing anything with SSL communication in the code that you've shown us, and I think we'll need a better idea of where the exception is getting thrown.  As it's written now, there's not enough information to diagnose this problem.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor the code that I have posted above is the whole stacktrace. The exception is thrown in the line beginning with ResultSet. Yesterday I stumbled upon in http://dbpedia.org/sparql that "Security restrictions of this server do not allow you to retrieve remote RDF data". I think this is the problem. But the thing I don't understand is that all the related posts about JENA use a similar code and it seems no one has encountered such a problem.